# Should there be a Casimir effect for superconductors?

Tags: superconductivity, casimir-effect

I was curious if a Casimir effect between superconductors makes sense theoretically and whether one has been detected experimentally.

I found the following paper: [arXiv:1902.09136](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09136) — which suggests people attempted to look for such an effect but couldn't find it.  (However, it was expected as the sensitivity of their equipment was not fine enough to measure the strength of the effect.)

Has anything happened since? Is a Casimir effect between superconducting plates at least theoretically sound?